# Google Drive Java Quick Start Guide Warning

Tags: java, google-drive-api

The following was the error.

```
WARNING: Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: document.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.google.api.client.http.FileContent.getInputStream(FileContent.java:71)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:361)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:418)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at DriveCommandLine.main(DriveCommandLine.java:56)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quickstart application uploads document.txt file from your local filesystem to Drive. Please place any file named document.txt on working directory of your application before executing the code.

Comment: I did! its in the src folder, the one with the class containing main.

Comment: Sorry.. thanks... I have added the file in the root and it worked. But " The file must be in the same location as the source code you paste from below" was given in the Quick Start Guide.

Comment: It seems like you are using Eclipse where working directory is not same as directory of source code. Quickstart cannot cover all possible cases. Sorry for that.

Comment: I just started getting this error. Any idea of what the fix is? I will try to use Builder.setApplicationName as it suggests. But it looks like a cache issue, as it is intermittent.

Comment: The warning comes from from line 47  - new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).build();. File handling happens only later.